# Adjusting the Scale on Bar Chart in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, bar-chart

So I am plotting to visualize the education difference between genders in a given dataset.
I group the employees by gender, summing their years_in_education with this code

```
df1 = df[["gender","years_in_education"]] #creating a sub-dataframe with only the columns of gender and hourly wage
staff4=df1.groupby(['gender']).sum() #grouping the data frame by gender and assigning it to a new variable 'staff4'
staff4.head() #creating a visual of the grouped data for inspection
```

Then I use a bar chart to plot the difference with this code >>

```
my_plot = staff4.T.plot(kind='bar',title="Education difference between Genders") #creating the parameters to plot the graph
```

The graph comes out as this >>

[image: Graph Before Scale]

But I observe the that scale of the y-axis is outrageous as the highest year in employment by the data is 30. I intend to adjust the scale to range from 0 - 30. I did that using `my_plot.set_ylim([0,30])` and the result of that was >>

[image: Graph after adjusting scale]

This graph is not reflective of the data as shown in the first. What can I do to change that?

Any ideas pls? How can I also change the orientation of the label on the y-axis.

Comment: *the highest year in employment by the data is 30*, do you want `df1.groupby(['gender']).sum()` or `df1.groupby(['gender']).max()`?

Comment: Your graph is reflecting what you tell it. I would recommend looking a bit further into this line: `staff4=df1.groupby(['gender']).sum()`

Comment: Do you want to rescale the data to 0-30, keeping the proportions?

Comment: `df1.groupby(['gender']).mean()`?

Comment: Oh yeah, that line was the problem.
This worked `df1.groupby(['gender']).max()` 
thank you @QuangHoang and everyone.